# Sharing a Global Matrix in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How can I share a global matrix with all mappers in Hadoop?

I know that sharing variables is done using:

> conf.set("testVar", "value1");

Then to get the value in the mappers:

> conf.get("testVar")

But what about the case of matrices? is it possible to share the matrix before starting to execute the map function or not?

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using hadoop's distributedcache feature. [DistributedCache](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) is a feature provided by the Map-Reduce framework to cache files (text, archives, jars etc.) needed by applications.Google it and you can find code example

Comment: But it caches files, right? how can I put the file in a matrix (e.g. integer matrix) before starting to execute the code?
I guess DistributedCache puts the file in the cache and opens it on each mapper side, isn't it?